# XLoadQueryFont Font not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts, x11, xvcg

I'm trying to use an old binary (HP VEX simulator: http://www.hpl.hp.com/downloads/vex) which uses VCG visualization tool (http://www.rw.cdl.uni-saarland.de/~sander/html/gsvcg1.html).

The binary fails because of a failed function call:

`#define VCG_DEFAULT_FONT "-*-courier-*-*-*--14-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"
char Xfontname[512] = VCG_DEFAULT_FONT;
panel_font = XLoadQueryFont(root_display,Xfontname);`

I am wondering if installing the font on the machine would solve this issue? If so, how can I install the font so that `XLoadQueryFont` function would detect it.

I am using an Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

I would appreciate any other proposed solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: is this a programming question? it does not seem like you are programming the binary or plan on using a programming solution for your problem. maybe checkout other forums for Ubuntu. also, you should provide any error codes from the program or otherwise better description of "failed function call". there should be an eror code or message that may anrrow down the problem. good luck!

Comment: Ah yes, it's not very programming question indeed. The programming bit of it is where does the x11 function `XLoadQueryFont` searches for fonts.

Comment: Issue solved here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428776/adding-a-font-to-x11-xloadqueryfont
Thanks for the feedback!